# TypeScript reuse type generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How to extend generic type generics of type to function? Is it possible to reuse generics without copy paste?

```
type T<FormType extends 'edit' | 'create' = 'create', RecordType extends Record = Record> = {
   type: FormType,
   record: RecordType
}

const func = <FormType extends 'edit' | 'create' = 'create', RecordType extends Record = Record>(props: T<FormType, RecordType>) => ...
```

How to extend this `<FormType extends 'edit' | 'create' = 'create', RecordType extends Record = Record>` from **type generics** to **function generics** without copy paste?

Comment: You can't. The closest you can do is create a type alias for `'edit' | 'create'`.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do is break it down to one Base type:

```
type GenericType = {
  formType: 'edit' | 'create'
  recordType: Record
}

type Base = {
  formType: 'edit';
  recordType: Record
}

type T<B extends GenericType = Base> = {
   type: FormType,
   record: RecordType
}

const func = <B extends GenericType = Base>(props: T<B['formType'], B['record']>) => ...
```

I find this helps with verbosity *a lot* especially as I add a lot of generics in.